# Reg Deployment catalog

Tags: silverlight, prism, mef

I am trying out a sample using deployment catalog. I have downloaded a sample application and tried that. When i executed that sample application , it was working fine.

When i tried to add new module and load using deployment catalog , it was not loading and the property which has allow recomposition is always showing null.

I have spent 1 day and still i could not able to load module using deployment catalog.

Anybody help me with very simple example of illustrating deployment catalog.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this level of detail it is hard to suggest specific solutions. If running examples would help:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/MEFDynamicLoading.aspx
- http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2010/03/08/building-hello-mef-part-iv-deploymentcatalog/
- http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/02/24/mef-silverlight-and-the-deploymentcatalog.aspx

I think the latter two are built against MEF betas, but using the RTM version should be close to identical if you find an example that helps with your scenario.